# Referring to a dictionary using an input

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So I have an input that takes the user input and uses it to try and locate the right dictionary using the key. It is linked up to a .dat file which all works fine and locates the dictionary.

If I simply enter the location prior to running the program like this it is fine:

```
print(useraccounts[56443]['forename'])
```

But when I use the input to fill in the '56443' section it won't work (the part that says 'id_find')

```
    id_find = input('Enter the unique student ID: ')

    if os.path.exists('useraccounts.dat') == True:
        with open('useraccounts.dat', 'rb') as x:
            useraccounts = pickle.load(x)


    print(useraccounts[56443]['forename'])



    print('Student Found: ')
    print('\nForename: ', (useraccounts[id_find]['forename']))
    print('Second name: ', (useraccounts[id_find]['surname']))
    print('DOB: ', (useraccounts[id_find]['dob']))
    print('Gender: ', (useraccounts[id_find]['gender']))
    print('Username: ', (useraccounts[id_find]['username']))
    print('Password: ', (useraccounts[id_find]['password']))
    print('Class: ', (useraccounts[id_find]['class']))
```

Here is what I get back. You can clearly see that it finds the dictionary where I inputted the key before running the program (George is the forename field) but doesn't work when it uses the input to find it.

```
Enter the unique student ID: 56443
George
Student Found: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/Documents/Homework/Computing/spelling bee George Taylor.py", line 335, in <module>
    teacher_menu()
  File "/Users/admin/Documents/Homework/Computing/spelling bee George Taylor.py", line 224, in teacher_menu
    student_edit()
  File "/Users/admin/Documents/Homework/Computing/spelling bee George Taylor.py", line 28, in student_edit
    print('\nForename: ', (useraccounts[id_find]['forename']))
KeyError: '56443'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
id_find = input('Enter the unique student ID: ')
```

Change to:

```
id_find = int(input('Enter the unique student ID: '))
```

Answer (score 3):

The dictionary is keyed by integer 56443, you are searching with the string "56443".